# Pandas filter values which have both null and not null values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a dataframe, need to filter out a list of elements in the first column, for which in second column there are both - Null and non-null values.

```
["1"]   ["2"]    
"A"    "Smthng"      
"B"    "sometext"      
"C"     NULL
"A"     NULL
```

For this case I should get `A`:

```
["1"]   ["2"]    
"A"    "Smthng"  
"A"     NULL
```

I did this, and it's working. But maybe you know how to do it faster, in one-line code.

What I have done:

```
NamesWithMissing = df[df['2'].isna()]['1'].tolist()
NamesWithMissing = df[(df['1'].isin(NamesWithMissing)) & (df['2'].notnull())]['1'].tolist()
df[df['1'].isin(NamesWithMissing)].sort_values(by="1")
```

#### UPD

Found interesting solution:

```
df.groupby('1').filter(lambda g: (g.nunique() > 1).any())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a mask using `isna` then `groupby` this mask by column `1` and `transform` using `nunique` to check for the condition where the group contains both null and non-null values

```
df[df['2'].isna().groupby(df['1']).transform('nunique').eq(2)]
```

---

```
   1       2
0  A  Smthng
3  A     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean indexing:

```py
m = (
    df.groupby("1")
    .transform(lambda x: (x.isna().sum() >= 1) & (x.notna().sum() >= 1))
    .values
)
print(df[m])
```

Prints:

```
   1       2
0  A  Smthng
3  A     NaN
```